# Is there an option or setting that prevents VLOOKUP from returning zero when it finds blank cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, formatting, spreadsheet, vlookup

Is there an option or setting that prevents `VLOOKUP` from returning zero when it finds blank cells or does not find the lookup value.

I do not want to suppress the zeros by formating them out. I want `VLOOKUP` to return the cell as it is or show NA if it can't find the value.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but there are some work arounds.

I usually just bring in an IF statement:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(*blah, blah, blah*)=0,"NA",VLOOKUP(*blah, blah, blah*))
```

And will often error trap it with:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(*blah, blah, blah*)=0,"NA",VLOOKUP(*blah, blah, blah*)),"NA")
```

Also, sometimes I will use conditional formatting for all cells = 0, show with white font etc.

And you can even try a customn number format like:

```
0;(0);""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the latest version of Excel, try using `XLOOKUP` instead.

To get rid of the zero, you can concatenate an empty string to the return_array.

For example:

`=XLOOKUP(lookup_value,lookup_array,return_array&"","NA")`

Concatenating the empty string to the return_array will of course cause all return values from that formula to be formatted as text. So, apply an appropriate wrapper function to re-convert to number formats:

`=VALUE(XLOOKUP(lookup_value,lookup_array,return_array&"","NA"))`

Answer (score 0):

Select the cell where you want to store the formula, and click the "Insert Function" button in turn to open the "Insert Function" option.

[image]

In the "Insert Function" dialog box, click the "Select Category" drop-down button and select "Logic" in the drop-down menu; select the "IF" function in the "Select Function" list box, click the "OK" button, and the "Function" will pop up Parameters" dialog box.

[image]

In the "Logical-test" parameter text box, enter your vlookup formula, and then you can select the content returned when true or false

[image]